# Lodash merge. How to connect two objects with ignoring null values?

Tags: javascript, lodash

My problem is that I want to mix my initial application state and state stored in other place. How can I connect two objects in javascript with Lodash with ignoring null values? Here is my code:

```
const initialState = {
  form: [
    {
      name: "car",
      value: 45000
    },
    {
      name: "cat",
      value: 50
    },
    {
      name: "shipping",
      value: 5
    }
  ],
  option: "A",
  money: 500000
};

const storedState = {
  form: [
    null,
    null,
    {
      name: "shipping",
      value: 12
    }
  ],
  option: "B"
};

const preloadedState = _.merge({}, initialState, storedState);
console.log(preloadedState);
```

What you can see from that console.log is that object:

```
preloadedState = {
   form: [
     null,
     null,
     {
       name: "shipping",
       value: 12
     }
   ],
   option: "B",
   money: 500000
};
```

I want to always ignore null values from storedState and keep in that places values from initialState. How can I achieve that? The effect I want should be:

```
preloadedState = {
   form: [
     {
       name: "car",
       value: 45000
     },
     {
       name: "cat",
       value: 50
     },
     {
       name: "shipping",
       value: 12
     }
   ],
   option: "B",
   money: 500000
};
```

Please for help,
Arthur

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use compact()

```
_.compact(preloadedState.form)
```

But it will also remove other "falsy" values, like 0, false, etc.

Other option is to use without

```
_.without(preloadedState.form, null)
```

In both cases, merge the results.

If you work with collections instead of arrays, either `filter` or `reject` should work too.

Comment: It should only ignore null. I need something that will ignore merging when value will be null. I am not able to achieve my wanted result at the end of my post with your advices. So maybe I need to ask: How to change all nested nulls in preloadedState to initialState values in same places?

Comment: Then _.without should do the trick. If it doesn't, please update your question with an example that doesn't work, and we'll try to figure it out together.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses two methods:

1. `mergeArrays` combines the two arrays and [reduces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) them to a Map. It merges objects with the same key. When done, it converts the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) back to array with [`Map.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
2. `cleanMerge` uses `_.mergeWith()` to combine objects recursively. It also merges objects in arrays using `mergeArrays`. The `cleanMerge` method accepts a clean callback, in this case [`_.without()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#without) with the argument `null` appended to the end of the list of arguments using [`_.partialRight()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#partialRight).

```js
const initialState = {"form":[{"name":"car","value":45000},{"name":"cat","value":50},{"name":"shipping","value":5}],"option":"A","money":500000};
const storedState = {"form":[null,null,{"name":"shipping","value":12}],"option":"B"};

const mergeArrays = (o, s, prop, mergCB) => [... // spread the .values() iterator back to array
  [...o, ...s] // concat both arrays
  .reduce((r, o) => 
    _.isObject(o) ?
      // if object, add to Map with the prop as the key
      r.set(o[prop], mergCB(r.get(o[prop] || {}), o))
      : 
      // if not object, add to map with a symbol as the key, to preserve the value
      r.set(Symbol(), o),
    new Map())
  .values()]; // get the Map values iterator

const cleanMerge = (o, s, cleanCB = _.identity) => _.mergeWith({}, o, s, (ov, sv) =>
  _.isArray(ov) ? 
    // if array, merge, and remove nulls
    cleanCB(mergeArrays(ov, sv, 'name', _.partialRight(cleanMerge, cleanCB)))
    : 
    // if not, let mergeWith handle the merge
    undefined);
  
const preloadedState = cleanMerge(initialState, storedState, _.partialRight(_.without, null));

console.log(preloadedState);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```